# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body move the returned value immediately after the => JS React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, arrow-functions

Following is my code which is giving me above mentioned error.

Code -

```
selectAll = (e) => {
    const dataList = this.state.appList
    const newArr = dataList.map(x => { return e.target.checked ? ({ ...x, checked: (<input type="checkbox" checked className="check" onClick={this.check} />)}) : { ...x }})
    this.setState({ appList: newArr })
  }
```

I tried by removing `return` but I am using if-else statement so I am sure it must be need though I tried but its giving error as well. Let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Remove both the `return` and the surrounding block delimiters. (You are not using an `if` statement anywhere)

Comment: @CertainPerformance thx a lot for answering it..fixed and working